# mysql aborted connections -- how to track down cause

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to debug a problem in PHP and I think I found a likely culprit. Mysql has aborted connections.

Is there anything in mysql logs that will help me pinpoint where the connection was dropped/why? (I have seperate DB + web Servers)

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
+------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value        |
+------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Aborted_clients                          | 150          |
| Aborted_connects                         | 86496        |
```

Comment: did you check the mysql logs for errors? i think there should be some error messages about this problem. or maybe in php error logs too. please take a look
if you are using apache2 webserver then the default location of error logs is `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and mysql is `/var/log/mysql.err`

Comment: mysqld.log (My error log) didn't indicate anything that I could find. I also check apache log and there wasn't anything in there too. I am using new relic for monitoring and have noticed a couple of very odd errors that could be related to the connections dropping. Do Aborted_client and Aborted_connects indicate dropped connections? Over what period of time did this happen?

Comment: it could be a couple of things, network errors, database server errors or like you said some php errors, without som more specific error messages it's impossible to tell

Comment: In my case it was a heartbeat monitoring script which just tested opening a socket to mysql server. Although the script ensured closing the socket, may be it was not _proper_ by the definition of mysql; because, after stopping it, the counts were not increasing any more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Aborted_connects` are clients who [attempt to connect and fail](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Aborted_connects). Usually this is because of incorrect credentials (wrong password or no matching host for the user).

I would start by turning on `--log-warnings` [as mentioned in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/communication-errors.html) and checking your error logs to help find the culprit of frequent connection failures.

Aborted connections can also be caused by clients trying to connect with invalid or malformed connection strings. Some monitoring applications for example just check the mysql port for connectivity and can trigger this. [This blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/08/23/how-to-track-down-the-source-of-aborted_connects/) has some examples of using packet level monitoring to try and pinpoint the issue.

`Aborted_clients` are the client not closing the connection properly. PDO and MySQLi both provide methods to correctly close a scripts connection when it's done.

Comment: I did a tcp dump and when I noticed that aborted connects went up I stopped it. It looks like some sort of monitoring service triggered that error. I am still trying to figure out the aborted clients piece.

Comment: fwiw - Another common cause of aborted connects is hitting the max_connections limit.  Until that limit is raised or connections drop below the limit every connect attempt will be aborted.  (This and other causes will be readily apparent in the error log.)

Comment: yet another case for this error – clients being killed. We have a setting that doesn't allow a request to go over 30s, so if the worker process (ruby, unicorn) is killed after 30s then there is this line in mysql log.